# Boolean type on mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking for a way to store boolean data in SQL. I couldn't find a boolean type in MySQL. I looked at the table on w3schools ([SQL Data Types](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp)) and didn't find a boolean type.

But I get the information that `TINYINT(1)` is used for boolean types.

Is it true, or is there another option?

Comment: w3fools is a pure crap "resource". If you'd bothered checking the ACTUAL mysql documentation, you'd see there's been a `bit` type in MySQL for a long time now: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-type.html  let this be a lesson. just because w3fools shows high up in google results doesn't mean they're actually a GOOD result. they waste more money on SEO that would be better spent on being USEFUL. Instead they choose to be widely seen crap.

Comment: @MarcB, I like your misspelling.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`BIT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/bit-type.html) data type to store boolean data ([like on T-SQL / SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/bit-transact-sql)):

```
CREATE TABLE `table_name` (
    `column_name` BIT(1)
);
```

On MySQL the data types [`BOOL` and `BOOLEAN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-syntax.html) are also available:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_name` (
    `column_name1` BOOL,
    `column_name2` BOOLEAN
);
```

The `BOOL` and `BOOLEAN` data types are synonyms for [`TINYINT(1)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html):

> These types (`BOOL` and `BOOLEAN`) are synonyms for `TINYINT(1)`. A value of zero is considered `false`. Nonzero values are considered `true`.

Answer (score 4):

There is a data type `BOOL` or `BOOLEAN` in MySQL:

> BOOL, BOOLEAN
>
> These types are synonyms for TINYINT(1). A value of zero is considered
>   false. Nonzero values are considered true:
>
> ...

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-overview.html